# can't translate an ajax popup

Tags: localisation

I can't translate something and i have no idea how to do it.
I need to translate an ajax popup that happens after you press add to card.

This wil give an popup from plugin (Ajax Filter and Cart - team V) that gives 2 buttons (Continue shopping and Proceed to Checkout) but i can't get this text translated.

I already tried:

- on the FTP: app/locale/nl_NL/Mage_Catalog.csv i added the translation lines here.
- on magento backend i put on translate inline but the buttons do not get the red square around them.

What can i do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on where the original text comes from. If it's defined in a phtml file, a model/helper or controller, but not wrapped in a php function call to `__()` then it can't be translated.

If it's defined in a JS file, the translation system works differently. So the string will need to be wrapped in a JS function call to `Translator.translate()` instead. There will also need to be a jstranslator.xml file with something like this in it:

```
<jstranslator>
    <validate-guest translate="message" module="checkout">
        <message>The text to be translated</message>
    </validate-guest>
</jstranslator>
```

If it's not wrapped then you can't translate it, so you'd need to modify the extension.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I mannaged to translate it. after 2 hours of searching in my ftp i found the 2 lines of text in a phtml file. i just changed the code in there.